# how to make sure one javascript function get caled after another function

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and don't know whether its using stack for keeping trace of function calling .

This is the code i got stuck with

```
function bounce(nIdx,bMulti)
{
    idDivread.style.display='';
    initBounceMgr();

    cBounceMgr.bounce(document.all.KnlTbl.rows[nIdx].cells[0].procName,bMulti);
    readKill();
}

function readKill()
{
    idDivread.style.display='none';
}
```

This bounce function is called by `onclick` event and i want to show a div as it has image of wait symbol. And this  is working but as i want to remove this wait symbol after function call is done i applied this `readKill` function. But then that image is not coming at all.
Seems that this function get called before these two functions.
What to do to make sure that `readkill` function get executed after this two function.

Comment: do `idDivread.style.display='block'` in your bounce function

Comment: the `cBounceMgr.bounce` is asynchronous probably; you could (if possible) pass `readKill` as a callback funciton to that method which will call it afterwards.

Comment: can you please explain me callback function

Answer (score 4):

They are being called in the order you would expect. The problem probably comes from the fact that if `bounce` is an animation or similar it probably returns immediately and does the animation asynchronously. So what it is in fact doing is showing the div, starting the bounce, then hiding the div and in the hidden div doing your bounce animation.

Usually methods that run like this will accept a callback parameter. That is a method that is called after they have finished doing what they want. In this case you would pass `readKill` in as the callback function instead of calling it directly.

I'm not sure what the cBounceMgr object is though so it is impossible to give you exact syntax to use.

Comment: its not an animation . it's an function which perform some kernel operation of stoping and then satring  of an operation

Comment: Ah, its that kind of bounce. The asynchronous comments still apply anyway. If its HTML I assume there is some async ajax stuff going on to do the start/stop. The key thing is that the bounce method almost certainly calls something asynchronous which is why it is then continuing running past that point and runing your readKill method before the bounce completes.

Comment: so can u help me by telling the way and the syntax in which it can be done

Comment: Not really. It all depends on your `bounce` function. The bounce function has to support taking a callback as one of its parameters. Callbacks are deliberately there to allow you to know when something has finished and run code at that point. If it supports it then the documentation should help, if not then what you want can't be done directly.